# How to use value returned by a method in another in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Java class inside which I have defined 3 methods.

```
public class Test {

    String session_id = null;

    public String login()
    { 
        //returns the session id
        return session_id;
    }

    public void read()
    {
        //use the session id returned from login() method
    }

    public void logout()
    {
        //use session id returned from login() method
    }
}
```

I want to know how I can use the session id that is returned in the `login()` method in the other two methods.

Comment: Well you could call `login` in each of those methods...

Comment: Call the login() method to assign a value to a String session_id reference then make the stuff you want with it in the read() and logout() methods.

Comment: note; your login() should return a String (with capital S) but I guess the compiler will let you know as well...

Comment: With the given code, session_id is always `null`...

Answer (score 3):

You can call login method in both of these methods.

```
public class Test {

    String session_id = null;

    public String login()
    { 
        //returns the session id
        return session_id;
    }

    public void read()
    {
        String session_id = login();
    }

    public void logout()
    {
        String session_id = login();
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to pass session_id as its instance variable and belongs to same class. Methods have access to it by default.

Answer (score 0):

So `session_id` is a global variable so you can simply use it:

```
public void read()
{
  String local_id = this.session_id
}
public void logout()
{
  String local_id = this.session_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead..

```
private String session_id; //make getter and setter

    public String getSession_id() {
        return session_id;
    }

    public void setSession_id(String session_id) {
        this.session_id = session_id;
    }


    public void login() {
        setSession_id(session_id);  //session_id is what you were returning in your code
    }

    public void read() {
        getSession_id(); //and store it in something
    }

    public void logout() {
        getSession_id(); //and store it in something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to the method that returns the relevant value. note in this instance you will not need an object as the call is within the same class as what is called. hence the code within the method will look like so:

```
String whatever = login();
```